# Create a new python list that shows the accumulated total from set numbers in another list without using for loops

Tags: python, list, for-loop, parallel-processing, vectorization

I have a python list (lpttg1 = [1,2,3,4,5]) and want to add the numbers in this list to create a new list with accumulated total. So the output list should be like this [1.0, 3.0, 6.0, 10.0, 15.0]. This can be done using a for loop as I have shown in the code segment below. I was wondering whether there is a vectorised form or any other method to remove the for loop and do the task.

```
lpttg1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
AcccumMeltlp1 = []
MMeltlp1 = 0.

for i in lpttg1:
    #print i
    MMeltlp1 = MMeltlp1+i
    #print MMeltbas_peri
    AcccumMeltlp1.append(MMeltlp1)
    
AcccumMeltlp1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are looking for `numpy.cumsum()` function is used when we want to compute the cumulative sum of array elements over a given axis.

```
import numpy as np
in_arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
output_array = np.cumsum(in_arr) 
output_array
```

```
array([ 1,  3,  6, 10, 15, 21])
```

[DOCS](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) for more help

Answer (score 0):

An approach with pandas, using [`cumsum`](https://www.w3resource.com/pandas/series/series-cumsum.php#:%7E:text=Cumulative%20sum%20over%20a%20Pandas,size%20containing%20the%20cumulative%20sum.&text=The%20index%20or%20the%20name,to%20None%20or%20%27index%27):

```
import pandas as pd

lpttg1 = [1,2,3,4,5]

AcccumMeltlp1=pd.Series(lpttg1).cumsum().tolist()

print(AcccumMeltlp1)
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools` to do so in the following way:

```
from itertools import accumulate

l = [1,2,3,4,5]
AcccumMeltlp1 = list(accumulate(l))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `functools.reduce`

```
from functools import reduce
lpttg1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
AcccumMeltlp1 = reduce(labmda x, y: x + [x[-1] + y], lpttg1, [0])[1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you have a list size below 10 and fixed all time.

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
newlist = [sum(lst[:1]), sum(lst[:2]), sum(lst[:3])]
print(newlist)
```